# using filter and group by in pig

Tags: sql, apache-pig

I am new to pig syntax and was wondering if someone can provide a hint for translating this SQL code into pig.

```
SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3)
FROM table
WHERE column5 = 100
GROUP BY column2;
```

So far I have:

```
data = LOAD....etc.
filterColumn = FILTER data BY column5 = 100;
groupColumn = Group filterColumn By column2;
result = foreach groupColumn Generate group, column1, SUM(column3) as sumCol3; 
DUMP result;
```

This does not work. The error message is "Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast."

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

[`SUM()`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#sum): Computes the sum of the numeric values in a single-column bag. It expects bag as its input. So, the `FOREACH ... GENERATE` would be,

```
result = foreach groupColumn Generate group, filterColumn.column1, SUM(filterColumn.column3) as sumCol3;
```

Also in the `FILTER` statement, to check for equality use `==`

```
filterColumn = FILTER data BY column5 == 100;
```

Comment: I forgot to specify where the column3 in SUM is coming from. SUM(filterColumn.column3)

Comment: @a.m. Yes.. Hoping this solved, could you please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The below pig commands can be used :

```
test=LOAD '<testdata>' USING PigStorage(',') AS (column1:<datatype>, column2:<datatype>,column3:<datatype>, column5:<datatype>);

A =FILTER test BY column5==100;

B = GROUP A BY column2;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, test.column1,test.column2,SUM(test.column3);

dump C;
```

Note that the usage of'PigStorage' and 'AS' are optional.

Hope this helps.